# how to send wei unit in call

Tags: solidity, transactions, payable

In a contract i was trying to send ether in wei units using the call method.

or is there any way to send fractions of ether like 0.048 ,

i wanna send `0.048`to my contract from an account which is`48563334682314852` WEI

example

```js
function sendEth() public payable{
uint256 amt=48563334682314852;
        (bool sent, ) = address(this).call{value:amt}("");
        require(sent,"Transaction failer");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do

```
(bool sent, ) = address(this).call{value:amt}("");
```

because in this context, the caller is the smart contract itself, so you are sending eth from the smart contract back to the smart contract, accomplishing nothing and burning gas.

What you want is to create a payable function that will be used to deposit into your smart contract. Like so :

```
  function deposit() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "You need to deposit at least 1 wei");
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  }
```

From there, you can use remix to send wei to your smart contract, by going in the "deploy & run transactions" tab, adding the desired amount of wei in the "value" box, and clicking on the red "deposit" button of your smart contract.

Hope this helps